# gesturesEnabled: false doesn't work for my react-navigation setup

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

```
    export const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
        [strings.route_login]: {
            screen: LoginScreen,
        },
        [strings.route_main]: {
            screen: MainNavigator,
            navigationOptions: {
                gesturesEnabled: false,
            }
        },
    },
    {
        headerMode: "none",
        navigationOptions: {
            gesturesEnabled: false,
        }
    }
);
```

I'd like to mention also that the MainNavigator is a DrawerNavigator and all it's children have the gesturesEnabled turned off! Unfortunately I can still swipe back to the LoginScreen in ios!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is my code :

```js
export const AppNavigator = StackNavigator(MainAppRoutes, {
 initialRouteName: 'firstscene',
 headerMode: 'screen',
 mode: Platform.OS === 'ios'
  ? 'modal'
  : 'card',
 navigationOptions: {
  cardStack: {
   gesturesEnabled: false
  }
 }
});
```

you should place gesturesEnabled in cardStack.

Comment: so changing it to modal solved it, now is it possible for the screen to have a normal transition (like a card)? from right to left? Thx!

Comment: yes it will have normal transition as card which will swipe from right to left

Comment: you r setting mode to modal thats why it inflated from below

Comment: Same thing, different form:     <RootStackNav.Navigator
      initialRouteName="More"
      navigationOptions={{
        cardStack: {
          gesturesEnabled: false
        }
      }}
    ></RootStackNav.Navigator>

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from 'react';

import { Alert, BackHandler } from 'react-native';
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';

const BackButtonExitHandler = () => {
  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      const backAction = () => {
        Alert.alert('Exit Application!', 'Are you sure you want to exit ?', [
          {
            text: 'Cancel',
            onPress: () => null,
            style: 'cancel',
          },
          { text: 'Exit', onPress: () => BackHandler.exitApp() },
        ]);
        return true;
      };

      const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener(
        'hardwareBackPress',
        backAction
      );

      return () => backHandler.remove();
    }, [])
  );
};

export default BackButtonExitHandler;
```

Just import this function in which screen you want not to go back

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the `gesturesEnabled` prop outside of the `navigationOptions`:

```
export const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
        [strings.route_login]: {
            screen: LoginScreen,
        },
        [strings.route_main]: {
            screen: MainNavigator,
            navigationOptions: {
                gesturesEnabled: false,
            }
        },
    },
    {
        headerMode: "none",
        gesturesEnabled: false,
    }
);
```

Comment: still no luck, thinking about reseting the stack, so it doesn't have where to go back!